# Perl System Command to Windows NUL or /dev/null

Tags: perl, system

Two questions actually:

I am creating a Subversion tag via my Perl script. Before I create that tag, I want to see if the tag already exists. One way I can do this is to run `svn ls $url` and see if the command fails:

```
my $error = system(svn ls $url);
if ( $error ) {
    say qq(URL "$url" doesn't exist. Create that tag);
}
else {
    say qq(Tag "$url" already exists. Abort! Abort!);
}
```

However, `STDERR` and `STDOUT` will both be pushed to the terminal. Therefore, I have to capture the output and dump it to null. In Windows, it's `NUL`. In Unix/Linux/Mac, it's `/dev/null`:

```
use Config;

my $null;
if ( $Config{osname} =~ /Win(32|64)$/i ) {
    say "This is a Windows system":
    $null = 'NUL';
}
else {
    say "This is Unix or Linux";
    $null = '/dev/null';
}

my $command = qq(svn ls $url > $null 2>&1);
my $error = system $command;
if ( $error ) {
    say qq(URL "$url" doesn't exist. Create that tag);
}
else {
    say qq(Tag "$url" already exists. Abort! Abort!);
}
```

That works, but it seems like a lot of work just to see if the URL exists.

Question #2: Is there a better way of doing this? I know of three ways you can execute a command in Perl and see if the command failed or not:

1. `my $error = system $command`
2. `my $output = qx($command)`
3. `open my $fh, '-|', $command`

In each of these, STDERR prints to the terminal, and must be captured. Is there a way to execute a command, and toss out STDERR and/or STDOUT and just see the command status?

---

### Answer

[Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17051086/368630) had a good idea. Redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT` and use `qx/.../`. I don't have to worry about the OS or `NUL` vs. `/dev/null`:

```
my $command = qq(svn ls $url 2>&1);
my $output = qx($command);
if ( $? ) {
    say qq(URL "$url" doesn't exist. Create that tag);
}
else {
    say qq(Tag "$url" already exists. Abort! Abort!);
}
```

Comment: You might want to *check* the value of `$?` to make sure it is consistent with `URL doesn't exist`, as something different may have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT` as you have in your own example. Then `qx/$command/`, or the data read from a pipe open, will return the combined output to both streams. The status is returned in `$?` on any platform.

Alternatively, have you considered [`Alien::SVN`](https://metacpan.org/module/Alien%3a%3aSVN)? The [`SVN::Client`](https://metacpan.org/module/SVN%3a%3aClient) module has a `ls` method that allows you to do exactly this without shelling out to the command-line program. If you pass a non-existent target then the module raises `$SVN::Error::FS_NOT_FOUND` which you can trap using [`Try::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/module/Try%3a%3aTiny).

Comment: Installing CPAN modules is a pain in this site. However, if I redirect STDERR to STDOUT (you said OUT->ERR way, but I think you meant ERR->OUT), and use `qx/../`, I don't have to worry about `NUL` vs. `/dev/null`. I can simply toss all the output away. Good idea.

Comment: You still have to worry about correctly forming string literals, though

Answer (score 0):

You could deal with both shells.

```
BEGIN {
    if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') {
        require Win32::ShellQuote;
        no warnings 'once';
        *shell_quote = \&Win32::ShellQuote::quote_system_string;
    } else {
        require String::ShellQuote;
        String::ShellQuote->import('shell_quote');
    }
}

my $null = $^O eq 'MSWin32' ? 'nul' : '/dev/null';
my $cmd = shell_quote('svn', 'ls', $url) . " >$null 2>&1";
system($cmd);
```

Or you could simply avoid the shell entirely.

```
use IPC::Run3 qw( run3 );
run3 [ 'perl', '-e', "warn 'abc'" ], \undef, \undef, \undef;
```

You could even avoid the `svn` executable entirely by using [SVN::Client](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SVN%3a%3aClient)!

Comment: This is a server box, and getting CPAN modules on it is a pain. Plus, it's Perl 5.8.8 (which is all we allow on servers). I have to request the modules be loaded, and then hope the service guys do it right. Otherwise, I'd just install `SVN::Client` which would make things way easier.

Comment: @DavidW.: That seems a very retro way of thinking. Do you know the reason behind preventing Perl upgrades?

Comment: Then why do you need cross-platform portability??

Comment: Well, that really sucks for you since all three solutions require a non-core module. You do realise that installing a module doesn't require any special permissions, right?

Comment: Paranoia. They have vendor supported Linux and all software upgrades must go through a very strict certification process. Any upgrade that could cause problems could cost us millions in lost revenue. A user install of Perl would trigger a lot of alarms because it could be an attempt to get around their security. They have thousands of servers connected to the Internet, and are wary of anything that could be a sign of malware. It's why I weigh the advantages and disadvantages of each CPAN module I might need.

Comment: @DavidW.: You can release a pure Perl module that is ostensibly part of your own code; it doesn't have to be installed in the "proper" place.

Comment: @Borodin Yes, I know, but that can be a pain. First, I have to determine if the module is really _Pure Perl_. Then, I have to determine its module dependencies. Then, I get to figure out if those dependencies are Pure Perl or not.

Comment: @DavidW.: Have you come across [deps.cpantesters.org](http://deps.cpantesters.org/?module=SVN%3A%3AClient&perl=5.10&os=any+OS)? It doesn't produce definitive results but it's certainly a help.